# OCaml: How can I return the first element of a list and after that remove it from the list?

Tags: list, functional-programming, ocaml, tail

I tried to use **List.hd** and **List.tl** for this task:

```
let takeCard fst deck =   
fst = List.hd deck   
List.tl deck
```

`List.hd` takes two arguments but I don't understand why.

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be helping to raise your content quality

Comment: `fst = List.hd deck` compares `fst` to the first element of `deck`, and ignores the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are a couple of misunderstandings here.

First, most types in OCaml are **immutable**. Unless you use [mutable](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2011sp/recitations/rec10.htm) variables you  can't "remove it from the list", you can only return a version of the list that doesn't have that first item. If you want to return both things you can achieve that using a [tuple](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2011sp/recitations/rec02-ocaml/ocaml.htm).

```
let takeCard deck = (List.hd deck, List.tl deck)
```

Second, List.hd only takes one element. OCaml leverages [currying](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/functional_programming.html). When reading an OCaml type signature the first parameters are what the function takes in and the last parameter is what the function returns. So List.hd's signature `'a list -> 'a` means that it takes in a list that contains (`'a` is used as a placeholder) and returns something of the type of stuff the list contains (in this case the first element).